# Unable to use mailx without sudo

Tags: sudo, cron, email, mail

I have recently "inherited" a number of cronjobs and other things from a former colleague. The scripts that are called regularly are supposed to send e-mails with error messages if something goes wrong, using a simple `mailx -s [...]` command. Since we migrated the crontab from my colleague to my user, no e-mails have been sent. I was very happy about the absence of problems, but it turned out that the `mailx`/`mail` command is simply not working.
I only receive e-mails to my address if I use `sudo mailx [...]`. The queue is empty according to `mailq`. I get no error messages. I can't seem to find any indication why I need `sudo` for sending e-mails.

Can someone please shed some light on why the command is not working without `sudo`, or what I could do to make it work without it? Is there some additional configuration I need to do? It must have worked for my colleague (I guess)...

Comment: Anything in `/var/log/mail.log` (or `mail.err`)? Oh, and what is your MTA?

Comment: Thanks @fkraiem and @anx! I didn't know about the `mail.log` yet. There's no `mail.err`, but the log clearly says that my user does not have the right permissions: "550 5.7.1: Client does not have permissions to send as this sender". I suspect that this is an Exchange problem, then, right?

Comment: The `mailx` command is not directly in the crontab, but called by a `python` script run by crontab. And I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that we're using Postfix. The problem appears to be that, if the command is called by me, the sender will be my username @ our domain, while a different sender address (probably the only one working) is used when I call `mailx` with `sudo`.

Comment: The easiest way to solve this - for me right now - seems to be to always set the sender manually with `-r`. Is there a way to configure `mailx` (or Postfix?) to automatically use a specific sender when I'm the user who calls the program? Otherwise, thanks for the help! Without you, I wouldn't have known what the problem is so fast.

Answer (score 0):

To add from adding the ssmtp.conf file to the group "mail", make sure to check that /etc/ssmtp is also under the group "mail" too. Permissions should also be something like drwxr-x--- you can do this by:

chmod 750 your_directory_or_file